# Срезы в python с отрицательным шагом

Tags: python, строки, срез

Не могу понять никак, откуда начинается отсчет 4, откуда 1. Если используется отрицательный шаг, и элементы среза извлекаются в обратном порядке, тогда и границы среза тоже нужно указывать в обратном порядке. Первой указывается правая граница среза, второй — левая:

```py
value = 'Hexlet'

# Символ с индексом 1 не будет включен в подстроку
value[4:1:-1]  # 'elx'
```

Вроде бы всё написано, но никак не могу в голове разложить, что нужно делать, сначала отобразить `Hexlet` как `telxeH`, а потом вести отсчёт элемента среза 4 и 1, или нет? Откуда считать то по итогу? Объясните именно логику что делать по порядку. Получается на выходе `'elx'` но как именно я не пойму. Спасибо.

Comment: Скопируйте параметры среза в `range` и увидите какие индексы будут взяты из строки: `print(*range(4, 1, -1))` -> `4 3 2`.  С четвёрки начнётся, не доходя до единицы остановится. Будут выбраны символы `'e' 'l' 'x'`.

Comment: Логика всегда одна. Начинается с первого числа, к нему добавляется последнее, пока не дойдёт до второго: `4 (-1) 3 (-1) 2 (-1) 1`. Последнее значение выбрасывается.

Comment: Так тут и указано в обратном порядке. 4 - правая граница, 1 - левая.

Answer (score 1):

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

```
Срез[Начало:Конец:Шаг] (Конец не включается)

value = 'Hexlet'
```

Индексы равнозначные "H"=[0]=[-6]

```
print(value[-5:-2]) #exl
print(value[1:4]) #exl
print(value[1:-2]) #exl
```

это одно и тоже

Шаг- просто прибавляется положительный слева направо, отрицательный наоборот.

```
print(value[::1]) #Hexlet 0=0, 0+1=1, 1+1=2, 2+1=3 ...
print(value[::-1]) #telxeH 0+(-1)=-1, -1+(-1)=-2, -2+(-1)=-3 ...
```

Comment: Отрицательную индексацию зря добавили. В вопросе её нет, а у ТС и с обычными индексами не складывается.

Answer (score 0):

У вас есть строка `value = 'Hexlet'` **-** `[0-H][1-e][2-x][3-l][4-e][5-t]`. Вы хотите извлечь подстроку, начиная с индекса **4** и заканчивая индексом **1** в обратном порядке. При использовании шага **-1**, элементы будут извлекаться в обратном порядке.

1. Вы начинаете с индекса **4** (правая граница среза) и берете символ с индексом `('e')`
2. Перемещаетесь влево на еще один шаг и берете символ с индексом **3** `('l')`.
3. Перемещаетесь влево на еще один шаг и берете символ с индексом **2** `('x')`.
4. Вы достигли левой границы среза с индексом **1** (левая граница среза) - он не включается в срез.

Полученная подстрока: `'elx'`.